# Javascript Date() milliseconds difference not adding up

Tags: javascript, function, date

I've created [this JSFiddle to illustrate my question](http://jsfiddle.net/DanEvans/RxVeG/).

It seems that 10 - 00 = 8 in this example.

The simple question: Why does #ha contain 8? Have I misunderstood something?

```
var a4 = new Date(2012,00,00,00,00,00,0010);
var b4 = new Date(2012,00,00,00,00,00,0000);
var c4 = a4-b4;
var d4 = document.getElementById("ha");
d4.innerHTML=c4;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an integer literal starts with `0` it is interpreted as an *octal* literal, not a decimal literal.  The literal `0010` has the same value as the literal `8` .  Remove the leading zeroes.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm still a bit confused then. If 0010 is interpreted as an octal literal since it starts with 0, why does 0019 - 0000 in the example link evaluate to 19? Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: I suppose it makes sense that JavaScript knows if the number contains a digit over 7 it's not octal.

Comment: @DanEvans Yes, JavaScript will interpret it as decimal in that case, which really is confusing and not very helpful.  I'd prefer it do like other languages and give a syntax error, but then again there are a lot of things about JavaScript that I don't like...

Answer (score 1):

using a leading 0 on a number is a signal to the processor that you're using an octal (base 8) number the same way that 0x indicates hex.

```
0010 - 0 == 010 == 8 in base ten
10 - 0 == 10 == 10 in base ten
0x10 - 0 == 0x10 == 16 in base ten
```